# Hibernate 4 and Spring 4 HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've looked trough all of the other posts regarding this issue and I can't seem to fix it.
Everytime I call a method from my service, I get the No Session found exception.

Here is my code:

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.baskettracer.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Dispatcher-Servlet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


</beans>
```

PersonDAO:

```
package com.baskettracer.dao;

import com.baskettracer.entity.Person;

/**
 *
 * @author 11302801
 */
public interface PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person, String> {

    void updatePassword(String pw);
    String hash(String s);
    String sha1(String s);
    String md5(String s);
}
```

PersonDAOImpl:

```
package com.baskettracer.dao.impl;

import com.baskettracer.dao.PersonDAO;
import com.baskettracer.entity.Person;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 *
 * @author Cornel
 */
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl extends AbstractDAOImpl<Person, String> implements PersonDAO {

    protected PersonDAOImpl() {
        super(Person.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePassword(String pw) {
        String hql = "update Person set wachtwoord = :pw";
        Query q = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("pw", hash(pw));
    }

    @Override
    public String hash(String s) {

        /*public function encrypt_password($password) {
         $salt = sha1(md5($password));
         $encryptedPassword = md5($password . $salt);

         return $encryptedPassword;*/
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public String sha1(String s) {
        java.security.MessageDigest d = null;
        try {
            d = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            d.reset();
            d.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            return d.digest().toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String md5(String s) {
        java.security.MessageDigest d = null;
        try {
            d = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            d.reset();
            d.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            return d.digest().toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

PersonServiceImpl:

```
    package com.baskettracer.service.impl;

import com.baskettracer.dao.PersonDAO;
import com.baskettracer.entity.Person;
import com.baskettracer.service.PersonService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author Cornel
 */

@Service("personService")
@Transactional
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{

    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Person get(int id) {
        return personDAO.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> get() {
        return personDAO.get();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void save(Person p) {
        personDAO.save(p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void delete(Person p) {
        personDAO.delete(p);
    }

}
```

Person:

```
package com.baskettracer.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 *
 * @author 11302801
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "personen")
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private Date dob;
    private String gender;
    private boolean available;
    private boolean injured;
    private boolean suspended;

    public Person(){};

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, Date dob, String gender, String username, boolean available, boolean injured, boolean suspended){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.username = username;
        this.available = available;
        this.injured = injured;
        this.suspended= suspended;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="persoonid")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="voornaam")
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(name="achternaam")
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Column(name="gebruikersnaam")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name="geboortedatum")
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @Column(name="geslacht")
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Column(name="beschikbaar")
    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    @Column(name="gekwetst")
    public boolean isInjured() {
        return injured;
    }

    public void setInjured(boolean injured) {
        this.injured = injured;
    }

    @Column(name="geschorst")
    public boolean isSuspended() {


  return suspended;
}

public void setSuspended(boolean suspended) {
    this.suspended = suspended;
}
```

}

Main:

```
package com.baskettracer.controller;

import com.baskettracer.entity.Person;
import com.baskettracer.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap map) {
        //Person p = personService.get(1);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards, Cornel Janssen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjusted the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer" />
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer.controller" />
```

in my dispatcher and inserted

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

into my applicationContext. now it works!! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `@Transactional` annotation somewhere. You could add it to the `PersonDAOImpl` class. This will make sure a session is opened and everything is cleaned up when it's done.

If you have an implementation for the `PersonService` you could add it to the class or any of the methods therein as well.

Comment: Yea I posted the wrong code, edited and now it shows the implementation of the PersonService.

Comment: Do you have another spring xml file that creates the personService?

Comment: No, only have the applicationContext.xml with configurations. Do I need to create the service in an xml file somewhere?

Comment: How is the service being found by the Spring container? Do you have a component scan tag somewhere?

Comment: I think you're missing <context:component-scan base-package="" />

Comment: I have this in my dispatcher-servlet.xml:
<context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer" />

Comment: Added the dispatcherservlet to the post

Comment: adjusted the 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer" /> 

to 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer.controller" /> 

in my dispatcher and inserted 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.baskettracer">
            <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
                                type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan> 

into my applicationContext. now it works!! Thanks all!